# How to get ajax values into php variables and set to sql queries?

Tags: magento-2.1, ajax

in my .phtml file inside of script tag there is a code like below

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
            var Calculation = function(evt) {

                var width = jQuery('#width').val();
                var height = jQuery('#height').val();

                //Ajax
                jQuery.ajax({
                showLoader: true,
                url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('helloworld/index/ajax'); ?>',
                data: ({
                        Width: width,
                        Height: height
                    }),
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json'
                })
                .error(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data.Width);
                    console.log(data.Height);
                });

            };
            $('#width,#height').on('change', Calculation);

        });
```

you can see, It will return some height and width

how can i use those values in sql query

```
<?php
    $sql = " SELECT price_component FROM base_price WHERE width="get width" AND height="get height" ";
?>
```

How can I do that

> How can i get those width and height in to php?

i used below code

```
<?php
echo $_POST['Width'];
?>
```

but it will give a error like saying undefined index Width

Comment: can u tell me how to do that im new to these things

Comment: Do you want to fire direct sql or you have model for it ? Are you asking how to get values of width and height in your ajax request.

Comment: I want to fire direct sql, i dont know how to get those height and width in to there.

Comment: can u give me a solution

Comment: im getting width and height from the ajax Request and i want to show in myphtml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned your ajax is working and you are getting the values you just need to update the values you can use jQuery to update it.

In the done function update it

```
.done(function(data) {
    jQuery('#width').val(data.Width);
    jQuery('#height').val(data.Height);
});
```

You can use some loader when you are firing ajax request so that user gets something is going on.

You can update the value anywhere Its my assume that I have shown above. You can update it in div or in any section where you want to display it using jQuery.

Hopes this helps it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can have height and width in your controller (`helloworld/index/ajax`) by this:

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
```

and sql query like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('employee'); //gives table name with prefix

//Select Data from table
$sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName;
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); // gives associated array, table fields as key in array.
```

Comment: I want to get those values im getting from ajax request into php variables

Comment: try with these two variables - `$post['Width']` and `$post['Height']`

Comment: please try to print $post and see what it has.

Comment: Is there another way it gives a error saying undefined index

Comment: please do not use `$_POST`. you need to get value by `$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();`. Then $post['Width']

Comment: please can u edit ur answer im new to these things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65634/discussion-between-sachin-agarwal-and-hemal).